# I need a link to return a value of true and process that value in PHP

Tags: php, session, hyperlink, anchor, logout

I have a button that takes care of the logout (`session_destroy`) part of my script. But because of style issues I need a link to do the trick.

```
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header("Refresh:0");
}
```

Does anyone knows how I process the link in php?

Comment: I'm lost on what you're asking for, you say you have a button that takes care of log out but because of style issues you need a link? html and style go hand in hand. What are you trying to achieve with php?

Comment: Unless you are catching your button click with javascript and sending an ajax POST, you will never have a `$_POST` variable result from a click on a link.

Comment: What is your current HTML? Probably just make a link and change `$_POST` to `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `$_GET['logout']`

your link would look like

`<a href="?logout=true">Logout</a>`

and your php

```
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header("Refresh:0");
}
```